# DataMensaje.find is not a function react node js

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, reactjs, find

en mi use effect traigo la info del back.

```
  useEffect(async () => {
        let currentDay = 4;//new Date().getDay();
        currentDay == 4 ? setDisabled(false) : setDisabled(true);
        service.find().then(data=>{setLoading(false), setData(data)})
        serviceMensaje.find().then(data=>{setDataMensaje(data)})
    }, []);
```

ahora el problema es cuando quiero seleccionar un tipo de dato para mostrar los datos en pantalla

```
 function tipoDeInteresado(tipoDeInteresado,tipoMensaje){
    setImagen({ imageTemplate:'',tamano:'200px !important' })
    const extrayendoIMG= extraerImagen(DataMensaje.find(element => element.TipoMensaje==tipoMensaje&&element.TipoInteresado==tipoDeInteresado).ImagenTemplate.data);
    const extrayendoContenido=DataMensaje.find(element => element.TipoMensaje==tipoMensaje&&element.TipoInteresado==tipoDeInteresado).Contenido;
    console.log(extrayendoIMG,"en que afecta",extrayendoContenido);
    switch (tipoDeInteresado) {
        case tipoDeInteresado = "Cliente":
            setDataMensaje({ imageTemplate:extrayendoIMG,contenido:extrayendoContenido});
        break;
        case tipoDeInteresado =  "Cliente Industrial":
            setDataMensaje({...DataMensaje, imageTemplate:extrayendoIMG,contenido:extrayendoContenido});
        break;   
        case tipoDeInteresado = "Ejecutivo":
            setDataMensaje({...DataMensaje, imageTemplate:extrayendoIMG,contenido:extrayendoContenido});
        break;         
        case tipoDeInteresado = "Interno":
            setDataMensaje({...DataMensaje, imageTemplate:extrayendoIMG,contenido:extrayendoContenido});
        break;           
        default:
        DataMensaje.contenido="Mensaje default"
            break;
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

DataMensaje es

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {IdMensaje: 1, TipoMensaje: 'sms', TipoInteresado: 'Cliente', Contenido: 'Mensaje de texto y cliente :)><', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
1: {IdMensaje: 2, TipoMensaje: 'sms', TipoInteresado: 'Cliente Industrial', Contenido: 'Mensaje de cliente industrial', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
2: {IdMensaje: 3, TipoMensaje: 'sms', TipoInteresado: 'Ejecutivo', Contenido: 'mensaje ejecutivo', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
3: {IdMensaje: 4, TipoMensaje: 'sms', TipoInteresado: 'Interno', Contenido: 'Mensaje interno', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
4: {IdMensaje: 5, TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico', TipoInteresado: 'Cliente', Contenido: 'Mensaje de texto y cliente :D', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
5: {IdMensaje: 6, TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico', TipoInteresado: 'Cliente Industrial', Contenido: ' victor', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
6: {IdMensaje: 7, TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico', TipoInteresado: 'Ejecutivo', Contenido: 'correo  y Ejecutivo', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
7: {IdMensaje: 8, TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico', TipoInteresado: 'Interno', Contenido: 'Mensaje co', ImagenTemplate: {…}}
length: 8
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

este seria data mensaje, deberia funcionar ya que es un arreglo, lo que busco es poder filtrar cada tipo de mensaje y asi mostrarlo en la consola, no debe ser algo dificil pero me tiene re loco, que esta vaina aveces funciona y aveces no, ayuda porfavor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me dice error, pero si no hago el set si funciona, alguien puede explicarme por que?

cuando hago si funciona, solo falla cuando uso el state, lo estoy haciendo como en la image, estoy empleandolo mal?

```
MensajeData.imageTemplate=extrayendoIMG;
```

aqui llamo la funcion, esto es cuando actualizo el tipo de dato en el front.

```
} 

 function validateOnChangeMensage(event){
    const input = event.target;
    const value = input.type === 'checkbox' ? input.checked : input.value;

    const result = FormValidator.validate(input);

     if (MensajeData.isEnabled=="block") {
         tipoDeInteresado(event.target.value,"correoElectronico");
         
     }else{
        tipoDeInteresado(event.target.value,"sms");
     }

    setMensajeData({
            ...MensajeData,
            [input.name]: value,
            errors: {
                ...MensajeData.errors,
                [input.name]: result
            }
    });

}

function handleMensajeDataChange(evt){
    const value = evt.target.value;
    var tipoDeCliente= document.getElementById('id-tipoInteresado').value;
    if(evt.target.name == 'tipoMensaje'){
        if(evt.target.value == 'correoElectronico'){
            tipoDeInteresado(tipoDeCliente,evt.target.value);
            setMensajeData({...MensajeData,[evt.target.name]: value, ['isEnabled']: 'block'});
        }else{          
            tipoDeInteresado(tipoDeCliente,evt.target.value);
            setMensajeData({...MensajeData,[evt.target.name]: value, ['isEnabled']: 'none'});
        }
    }else{
        setMensajeData({...MensajeData,[evt.target.name]: value});
    } 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Proba en vez de hacer un find, barrer el DataMensaje con Object.entries. Porque parece ser un objeto, no un array.

Comment: puse mas info, podrías mirar?, gracias

Comment: En que momento llamas a la función tipo de interesado?

Comment: cuando realizo un cambio en el modal donde muestro los datos, si selecciono un tipo distinto de cliente

Comment: service y serviceMensaje que son?, de que tipo? vienen de un backend?